# How to make log and report active in robot framework ride?

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

I noticed log and report of robot framework ride as inactive on machine which I am connecting remotely. Could you please tell me how to make this two icon active?[image: enter image description]

Comment: I had this issue a while back when I used RIDE. I am not sure if it was a coincidence or not, but try pointing to a different directory for each file using the arguments input field. For example: `pybot -N RIDE_Test -r <YourPath> -l <YourPath> -o <YourPath>` If I remember correctly this worked for me..

Comment: Did that work? Or has something else helped you?

Comment: No, no success yet. Are you suggesting to me try this pybot -N RIDE_Test -r <YourPath> -l <YourPath> -o <YourPath> in command prompt? If yes then it is not working there, I am getting error message

Comment: Im suggesting you enter that line, in the Arguments Text Box below the 2 buttons. and where it says <YourPath> enter a Path for the files to be generated in. For example: `C:\NewFolder\AutomationLogs`. Once that has been inputted, hit play, like you normally would, and the buttons should become available - Hopefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this line inside your "Arguments" input within RIDE; just below the two buttons.

```
--outputdir C:/AutomationLogs --timestampoutputs
```

I think you need to place the files in a non temp directory for RIDE to recognise what they are - or something like that.